# how to use CUDA for multiplying sparse matrices(over gf(2) field) for block lanczos algorithm?

Tags: cuda, gpu, sparse-matrix, multiplication

I have an Academic project to do which relates to block lanczos algorith (Montengro's version). I have a problem designing the algorithm for the implementation of block lanczos, can anyone suggest me what path should I take for the sparse matrices that arise in this algo to multiply. They can be large ranging around 1M X 1M. I have gt 330m cuda enabled gpu with me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [CUSPARSE](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2_prod/toolkit/docs/CUSPARSE_Library.pdf) (included with the CUDA Toolkit) and/or [CUSP](http://code.google.com/p/cusp-library/) (open source)?

Comment: yeah I mean they are for matrices which have elements that are larger than 1, so those implementations will not benifit me because my matrix has elements only either 1 or 0